# Deeplinking for an Appcelerator's application using Branch IO for both iOS and Android Platform

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, branch.io

I would like to implement a deeplinking in my Appcelerator's application for both platforms. I already created a link in branch.io and successfully triggered my application after setting up their URI scheme.

My problem is, I would like to pass additional parameters in my branch.io link, and I want my app to receive the value of the parameter specified in the link.

For example: 
Branch IO Link : myapp.app.link
my target link should have parameter link : myapp.app.link?$pageID=page2

Once the application was launched, I would like to get the "page2"

Note that I already see this code https://github.com/BranchMetrics/titanium-branch-deep-linking. Unfortunately, I really dont understand how I will implement it.

ADDITIONAL UPDATE:
I already created a link https://branchIOdomain/iosaohfndsvnsd and setup a key value pair in the Deeplinking tab. 
key: $pageID
value: page2

But I do not know how to received the value in the application.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here: what you're describing is exactly how Branch works when fully configured. It sounds like you have everything set up to successfully launch the app, so the next step is to make sure you're starting a Branch session to retrieve all the link data (including the parameters you've added).

You can find a guide for doing this, along with the most recent code examples, [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/titanium/)

Comment: Thank you. The documentation is very helpful. :)

Comment: Just a follow up question, I have added this code: Ti.Android.currentActivity.addEventListener("newintent", function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("inside newintent: " + e);
            branch.initSession();
        }); but I think, whenever I tried to launch the application using the link I created, it is not getting inside this code.

Comment: Hmmm...I think we may need to see your full code to debug this further. Would you mind [submitting a ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) to the Branch Integrations team? If you want to try digging in yourself, we also have a [Titanium testbed app](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/titanium-branch-deep-linking) with all of this implemented.

Comment: Hi Alex, I successfully initialized branch in my application and retrieve my data. But I am having issue with the intent... For example, the application is already open and the user browse/click a link outside, it should still make the app on foreground and go the page I want... Where do I need to put the add eventlistener? Should it be on the activity that I want to launch or generally in currentActivity?

Comment: Follow up question: I dont know what is happening, previously my code worked. I was able to retrieved all the data from the initSessionFinished callback, but right now, I always experience "Trouble initializing Branch. Unable to reach the Branch servers, please try again later." I have to uninstall, then install the application to make it work again one time. Then I will have the same error again.

Comment: Without seeing the details of your implementation, this is tough to debug. Could you go ahead and [submit that ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) so we can help you look into this in more detail?

Comment: Hi Alex, I already created a ticket for this issue. It has nothing to do with the INTERNET permission. The main reason is the WRITE_STORAGE permission. If that is being used and turned-on, the issue will always occur. I even tested it on the tesbed sample application that you guys provided. Just manually set the Storage Permission on Device Setting and you will encounter the issue.

Comment: That is really strange! Thanks for submitting the ticket - we will get to the bottom of this

Comment: Hi Alex, The issue I raised wasn't resolve yet. :) Do you know anyone that can actually resolve the issue and not create new issue? https://github.com/BranchMetrics/titanium-branch-deep-linking/issues/76

Comment: It sounds like this may be a problem with our latest Titanium SDK release. We are investigating and will update that github thread with more details. Sorry for the delays, and thank you for your patience!

Comment: Hi Alex, the issue wasn't resolve yet. I am still waiting for it but I was able to make  some work-around. Right now, I am experiencing a different issue like this one: https://mobilegrowth.org/questions/question/deepview-always-redirects-to-app-store/ . Everything is already set, Universal link is already working but if the user tap the "Open The App" button in deepView, it directs to AppStore instead of the installed application. I also add the applinks:xxxx-alternate.app.link in the Entitlements.plist but still doesnt work.I guess, the same issue from the link I provided re-occur?

Comment: @AinneTupas no recurring server issues, to my knowledge. We'll need to look directly into your implementation to debug this — could you [submit an Integrations ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) with full details of your config?